# How to get extra JSON data during a POST request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My goal is to receive a JSON with all the information necessary to create a user, along with something extra that I'll use to create another object, all in one go using the recently created user and the additional information sent through the JSON. For context, my JSON currently looks like this:

```
{
   "first_name": "John",
   "last_name": "Doe",
   "username": "newuser",
   "email": "johndoe@hotmail.com",
   "password": "somepassword",
   "profile_image": null,
    "type": 2
}
```

`type` is the information not necessary for the creation of the user. My custom create function is looking like this, currently:

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'id', 'password', 'profile_image']
        read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'is_staff']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        types = self.request.data.get("type")
        create_user_type = UserType.objects.create(user=new_user, type=types)
        return create_user_type
```

It suffered a lot of changes after looking into the Django Rest Framework documentation, stackoverflow questions, and debugging. If I run the code the way it is now, This is what I get:

```
AttributeError at /user/
'UserSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'
```

So I assume this happens because you can't get request through doing `self.request`. I tried placing this create in the viewset because I realized things worked slightly different there, but then this happens:

```
TypeError at /user/
create_user() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Request
```

I can edit my question to add any information I forgot. I should also note that the user is created regardless of the error, but my goal is to create both the user and the other object. How could I get type from self?

Comment: You need to show how `create` is being called here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for, so this might be a naive answer, but this is the custom create function that comes as a functionality with Django Rest Framework. What do you mean by calling it?

Comment: What he means is, this is the _definition_ of `create()` method of `UserSerializer`, you MUST be instantiating an object of this class somewhere (view functions ?), and calling this method on that class. Providing that will give a clear picture of how you are using these definitions

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, you cannot get it from `self`, but you can get it from somewhere else.

If you note the second error, it says

> ```
> TypeError at /user/
> create_user() argument after ** must be a mapping, not Request
> ```

which means in the `new_user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)` definition, `validated_data` is a `Request` object that you are passing.

You can try `validated_data.get("type")` to get the type!

DISCLAIMER: Make sure your APIs are secure. I'm also fairly new to this, not sure passing entire request objects is safe

**EDIT:**
Understanding the data types of objects being passed around into functions will clarify a lot of things for you. After you moved the code-block to viewset, did you change how things interfaced?

**EDIT (2):**
Responding to your comment here:

> ```
> types = self.request.data.get("type")
> ```

The Request object will most-likely have deserialized data, which in Python generally means an object of `dict()` `type`. This is why you could use `.get()` on that object (unless you specified a cls as a hook to interpret the data differently).

This means, data-types supported by serialized JSON (strings, numbers, list/array, JSON object), would be str/bytes/unicode, int/float, list, dict in Python.

So, `type(types)` here really looks like it would be an `int`. (You say it's `"2"` in the comment, is that correct? In that case, your `type(types)` should give `str`).

If you want to use this value in the next command, you will have to probably create an object of `Types` class passing this value in it's constructor (I don't know how it looks, just a guess).

> ```
> create_user_type = UserType.objects.create(user=new_user, type=types)
> ```

This should resolve your problem, or point you into understanding it better at the least...

Comment: @Luisffx, try this method. Are you sure, in the second method, the user is created? The call fails at exactly that step where you are calling `create_user()`..

Comment: Your answer was very helpful for me to understand the second error, thanks! I forgot to specify that the second method of mine doesn't create any users. I tried this out, and now the error says ValueError: Cannot assign "2": UserType.type must be a "Types" instance. I thought passing that argument to the respective model would be enough to create it, but I'm once again unsure how to proceed. To get this error, I removed the two asterisks from validated_data (at least for the time being) and tried something slightly different from what you said, keeping the rest of the code as it was.

Comment: Yeah, that should work, please note that without concrete code snippets or evidence, all my answer's are merely speculation of what the issue might be. The best it can do it point you in some direction, rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be approached in more elegant way.

```
class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  type = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True, required=False) #optionl 'type' integer field

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'id', 'password', 'profile_image', 'type']
    read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'is_staff']

  def create(self, validated_data):
     type = validated_data.pop('type')
     user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
     create_user_type = UserType.objects.create(user=user, type=type)
     return user
```

The UserSerializer won't return a `UserType` object. It will throw an error.
If you want to return the `UserType` object along with `User` object you have to make a separate serializer for `Usertype` and use it as a nested in `UserSerializer`.